# Golang String Formatting

Tags: string, go

I have the below code,

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
    var s1 []int
    //s2 := []int{}

    fmt.Printf("%d, %d, %T, %t, %#[3]v\n", len(s1), cap(s1), s1, s1 == nil)
}
```

and the output is,

```
0, 0, []int, true, []int(nil)
```

Im really confused with the use of "%[3]v",.. since Im passing only 4 arguments...

The output I was expecting is

```
0, 0, []int, true
```

But "[]int(nil)" in the output is confusing me a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can check in the [fmt package documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt):

> Because an explicit index affects subsequent verbs, this notation can be used to print the same values multiple times by resetting the index for the first argument to be repeated:
> `fmt.Sprintf("%d %d %#[1]x %#x", 16, 17)`
> will yield "16 17 0x10 0x11".

So in your specific example, with the use of `%#[3]v` you are printing again the third argument in a default format `%v` for a nil slice `[]int(nil)`.

Answer (score 2):

If u want to get `0, 0, []int, true`, pls use this:

```
fmt.Printf("%d, %d, %T, %t\n", len(s1), cap(s1), s1, s1 == nil)
```

Your code:

```
fmt.Printf("%d, %d, %T, %t, %#[3]v\n", len(s1), cap(s1), s1, s1 == nil)
```

`%#[3]v` refers to the third argument, which is s1. `[]int(nil)` is the default representation of an empty slice of integers.

Comment: now i get it :) ..got confused because of [3] index